# How can I create a two-dimensional array containing ArrayLists?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, libgdx

How can I create a two-dimensional array containing ArrayLists? Something like this :

`ArrayList<Character>[][] myArray = new ArrayList<Character>[][];`

and would it be ok to do the following :

I need to compare the position of some characters with the position of the buildings in my map. Several buildings can belong to the same tile, but one can be drawn in front of the character and the other behind him. This comparison has to be done all the time in the game, with every character.

I am trying to update an array of characters each time a character is moving from one tile to another. Then the render method should look for how many characters, if any, are in a specific tile, and loop over the characters in this tile to draw them in front or behind the buildings.

Something like this :

```
//init
ArrayList<Character>[][] arrayOfCharacters = new ArrayList<Character>[][];

//each tile in the map
for (int y = 0; y < 9; y++){
    for(int x = 9-1; x >= 0; x--){
        if ( arrayOfCharacters[y][x].length > 0 ){
            for ( int i=0, i< arrayOfCharacters[y][x].length; i++ ){
                //compare which building is in front or behind the characters
                //then
                characterInThisTile = index of each character in arrayOfCharacters[y][x] 
                spriteBatch.draw(characterInThisTile, x_pos, y_pos, tileWidth, tileHeight);
            }   
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ArrayList<Character>[][] arrayOfCharacters = new ArrayList[9][9];
for(int i=0;i<arrayOfCharacters.length;i++){
      for(int i2=0;i2<arrayOfCharacters[i].length;i2++){
            arrayOfCharacters[i][i2]=new ArrayList<Character>(20);
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A two dimensional array is an array of arrays - it means that the structure looks something like:

```
[0,0][0,1][0,2][0,3] -> sub array 1
[1,0][1,1][1,2] -> sub array 2
[2,0][2,1][2,2][2,3][2,4] - sub array 3
```

Notice how the number of elements in each sub array does not have to be the same. You could create the above array as (I am using integers  your type would vary as necessary):

```
int[][] a = new int[3][]; // The number of sub arrays or the first argument should be defined. 
// The number of elements in each sub array need not be known at compile time though
```

So if had to do the same thing with an ArrayList, an array inside an array would translate to a list within a list. So you could do something like:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> arrayList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
```

Since an ArrayList object can expand dynamically, the structure would be something like:

```
Row [0] -> [0][1][2]..... // and so on
Row [1] -> [0][1][2]..... // and so on
Row [2] -> [0][1][2]..... // and so on
```

Entering elements into this would be done very similarly using nested for loops.

Comment: With the `List` alternative there should be another level to get something equivalent to a `List[][]` (i.e. two-dimension array containing lists): `List<List<ArrayList<Character>>>`

Answer (score 1):

You could make a class and then make Objects using that class that stores an `ArrayList<Character>` as an instance variable.

First make a class that has a instance variable `ArrayList<Character>`
that also has a getter, setter and constructor.

```
//Make Objects that will have an ArrayList<Character>
    public class ArrayOfChars {
        private ArrayList<Character> list;
        //Constructor
        public arrayOfChars(){
            this.list = new ArrayList<Character>();
        }
        //Getter
        public ArrayList<Character> getList(){
            return this.list;
        }
        //Setter
        public void setList(ArrayList<Character> list){
            this.list = list;
        }
    }
```

You can now use this class to make Objects and store that Objects in a 2D array
These Objects can store and `ArrayList<Character>` that can be used.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayOfChars[][] myLists = new ArrayOfChars[9][9];
        //initialize the 2d array so that it is filled with Empty ArrayList<>'s'
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
                ArrayOfChars thislist = new ArrayOfChars();
                myLists[i][j] = thislist;
            }
        }
        //You can now use it like a 2d array of objects
```

Here are some ways you can use this `2D-Array` of `ArrayList<Character>`

```
//Iterate like this
        for (int row = 0; row < 9; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < 9; col++) {
                myLists[row][col].getList().get(index);
                //or
                myLists[row][col].setList(list);
            }
        }


        //Add to a list
        myLists[2][5].getList().add(new Character('H'));

        //Set a list of characters
        ArrayList<Character> useThisList = new ArrayList<Character>();
        useThisList.add('F');
        useThisList.add('G');
        useThisList.add('L');
        myLists[3][7].setList(useThisList);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use list of lists, which is more dynamic.

```
List<ArrayList<Character>> list = 
new ArrayList<ArrayList<Character>>();
```

Comment: This may be good advice, as a comment, but it's not an *answer* to the question that was asked.

Comment: And it lacks a level as well: to get something equivalent to the question would be a `List<List<ArrayList<Character>>>`

Comment: Thanks, I read that Lists are slower than arrays, but it is maybe ok if I only call indexes, I don't know I will try.